# Most pythonic style for function calls with multiple params

Tags: python

Which is more Pythonic:

*Style one:*

```
    self.partitions.append(
        Partition(
            self.current.bottom, self.current.lower, boundary))
```

*Style two:*

```
    self.partitions.append(Partition(self.current.upper,
                                     self.current.top,
                                     boundary))
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, neither. There is usually no reason why you cannot split such logic into 2 steps:

```
part_obj = Partition(self.current.upper, self.current.top, boundary)
self.partitions.append(part_obj)
```

Comment: I agree it looks a lot tidier, and in this particular scenario may work. I personally dislike the extra declaration, but may be a needed sacrifice for readability.

Comment: However that solution is not scalable, what do you do when you have 6 params and variables name are not short?

Comment: @cardycakes, Well, that's another question :). I would *still* split into 2 statements and split the first multiline each time I reach 80-character limit.